# Is it possible to get full url (including origin) from route in VueJS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

In this example:

```
const resolved = this.$router.resolve({
  name: 'about'
})

console.log(resolved.route.path)
```

Is it possible to get route with origin included? Like, if the url is `site.com/about`, the code would give `/about`, so I'll need to append origin myself: `window.location.origin + resolved.route.path`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, not from the router.

Even the router's [`base`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#base) property is relative to the app root:

> The base URL of the app. For example, if the entire single page application is served under /app/, then base should use the value "/app/".

[`$route.fullPath`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#route-object-properties) also begins at the app root.  The docs describe it as:

> The full resolved URL including query and hash.

Comment: How to get full URL? I'm not able to get the full url from window

Comment: In Nuxt.js it would be a concatenation like `ctx.req.headers.host + ctx.route.fullPath`

Comment: This worked with me `ctx.window.location.origin + ctx.route.fullPath`

Answer (score 15):

I've been using this (tested with vue-router v4, browser only):

```
const route = router.resolve({ /* your route here */ });
const absoluteURL = new URL(route.href, window.location.origin).href;
```

*Edit*: Used `location.origin` instead of `location.href` since `resolve().href` already includes `base`.

Comment: OP mentioned he was doing `window.location.origin + resolved.route.path`.  This question was specifically about whether he could obtain the path directly from the router

Answer (score 0):

Previous responses omit the `pathname`. If the page is deployed on `/app/` and if you use `hash` mode in router, you will need this.

BTW the following code should works all situations.

```js
const route = router.resolve({ /* your route here */ });
const absoluteURL = new URL(route.href, window.location.origin + window.location.pathname).href;
```